# View component doesn't update when row is added to list

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this view with a viewmodel too. I have an issue when I click on the add button the setRowView doesn't update with a new row. I have tried to change med my @StateObject to an @ObsvervedObject, but that didn't helped...

My SetViewModel is a class which also conform to the ObservableObject.
Exercise is also a class where the set property is and @Published.

```
class ExerciseCardViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var execise: Execise
    
    init(execise: Execise) {
        self.execise = execise
    }
    
    func addSet() {
        execise.sets.append(DBSet(number: execise.sets.count + 1))
    }
    
    func deleteSet() {
        execise.sets.removeLast()
    }
    
    func createSetViewModel(sets: DBSet) -> SetViewModel {
        SetViewModel(sets: sets)
    }
}

struct ExerciseCard: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ExerciseCardViewModel
    
    var deleteExercise: (Execise) -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.execise.sets) { set in
                SetsRowView(sets: viewModel.createSetViewModel(sets: set))
                    .listRowBackground(Color.theme.TBBlack)
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                button(action: {
                    viewModel.addSet()
                },
                       icon: "plus.circle",
                       title: "Set",
                       backgroundColor: .green)

                if !viewModel.execise.sets.isEmpty {
                    button(action: {
                        viewModel.deleteSet()
                    },
                           icon: "minus.circle",
                           title: "Set",
                           backgroundColor: .red)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.theme.TBLightGray)
        .padding()
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            .foregroundColor(.theme.TBBlack))
    }

    private func button(
        action: @escaping () -> Void,
        icon: String,
        title: String,
        backgroundColor: Color) -> some View {
        Button {
            action()
        } label: {
            Text("\(Image(systemName: icon)) \(title)")
                .frame(width: 100, height: 30)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(backgroundColor.opacity(0.3))
                .cornerRadius(8)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you guys can help me :D

Comment: On the Exercise card is that how you init your VM? If so I think it should be @StateObject var vm: ExerciseCardViewModel = ExerciseCardViewModel()

Comment: No I actually init it from another view 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710726/swiftui-view-updating/68713038#68713038

Comment: StateObject should always be private but my guess is that Excercise and are sets are reference types and not value types or something along the chain. Every ObservableObject needs a property wrapper to observe changes.

Comment: If I changed it too value types, the data is only alive within that view. which means I don't have acces to it in the parent view...

Comment: Try adding objectWillChange.send() in the addSet function before appending the new object. Maybe it is that. I answered I similar question some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77802118/what-is-the-correct-approach-to-refresh-a-view-based-on-changes-to-objects-insid/77802207#77802207. You should also consider injecting the ExcerciseCardViewModel from its parent view instead of passing it down directly, retrieving it as an @EnvironmentObject.

Comment: Binding is a two way connection between a source of truth and a value type. if you use reference types you have to observe them at every level. But you can try the new `@Observable`. Calling `objectWillChange` on `ExerciseCardViewModel` every time and exercise or a set changes will become unscalable and full of bugs. You would be redrawing everything every time instead of targeted redraws.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

Comment: Good to know. You are right. Although I imagined it was doing something like that behind the scenes. I've actually never used it in my projects. I suggested it just because it worked for another user. By the way @Observable is only available on iOS 17+, we don't know the minimum deployment target the guy is using.

Comment: @MatBuompy a lot of people recommend that because it is “easy”. It just overlooks all the hard work SwiftUI does to maintain efficiency. SwiftUI has its own set of rules and we just have to play by them, lol.

Comment: @MatBuompy the link I posted has samples for ObservableObject too very detailed old vs new.

Comment: @loremipsum I've seen it :)

Answer (score 0):

Dear [Frederik Hjorth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8677958/frederik-hjorth),

you seem to be facing a problem with nested `@Published` variables. I experimented with something very similar:

```
class ExerciseProgram: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var currentExercise: Exercise
    @Published var currentSet: Int
}
```

The name of the ***currentExercise*** is not a problem since it only changes when a whole new Exercise class is assigned and `ExerciseProgram` is automatically aware when the object referenced  by `currentExercise` changes.

In the case of `currentExercise.currentSet` (on the code above, I needed to make the `ExerciseProgram` itself contain a `@Published` property mirroring the data of my **set**.)

If you have `@Published` data nested in different layers of your code it becomes very messy. I personally like to use a ViewModel which is the only ObservedObject the View knows of, and make this class fetch/adapt and return data directly to the View, who's only aware of the ViewModel and the values it provides, everything else being transparent.

[Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710726/swiftui-view-updating/68713038#68713038)

Comment: So I just have to understand. Do I make a new object which going to look like this or similar maybe: 
```
    class ExerciseProgram: ObservableObject { 
        @Published var currentExercise: Exercise
        @Published var currentSet: Set
    }
```
And then my viewModel ExerciseCardViewModel contains my new object?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You can have a lot of layers and different objects/services behind `ExerciseProgram`, but everything `@Published` must be right under `ExerciseProgram`.

Comment: @Frederick Hjorth, did my suggestion work (or even made sense to you)? I can try to write more code here or communicate in another manner. Cheers,

Comment: Sorry have been on vacation so haven't look much on it. But I have it a bit hard to figured out how to link sets and exercises, if I can't have nested @published properties?

Comment: Is there any way I can show you some more context? about my setup so far?

Comment: I think you’ve shown enough context, I’ve created objects with a similar interface to your code and found the same problem as you did. It turns put you can’t have and @ObservableObject inside another one, I’ve found there’s quite some discussion on the web about it. Ive found this on linkedin 
https://www.linkedin.com/posts/mohammad-azam-5537993_swiftui-activity-7158961708688891904-5aak?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_ios

Comment: Okay, I think I have solve that problem for now. but what I don't understand is, if I for instance make a change in another child view, every child view in the parent view will be redrawn

Comment: @FrederikHjorth does the redraw cause any problem? It's very common on SwiftUI, and I wouldn't really worry about it unless it looks weird or causes unwanted animations etc. It it does, then I'd need more context like the code for the View and the Exercise. Otherwise feel free to upvote my answer :)

Comment: It is kind of strange. I have a view where I setup the program. Where the user can input the name, add exercises and for every exercise you can add sets. So for instance if I add an exercises and add sets to that exercise and after that change the name, the sets array will change to not contain any sets. I can add some code. but I might think that's better to do that in an answer so the formatting is alright I guess?